# jquery hover parent div

Tags: jquery

I have a problem with the hover, I have a parent div and a child div. The problem is if i hover the parent div then the link "delete" appear in child div, but when I point my mouse in link "delete" it was blink. Maybe because mouseover and mouseout still work even I'm on child div.

thanks in advance
Tirso

```
 <div onmouseover="delete_comment_show('.$row_comments->id.')" onmouseout="delete_comment_hide('.$row_comments->id.')">
     <div><div>   'this is the child div which link "delete" will appear"
 </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

don't use inline javascript if you're using JQuery!  Add your script in a separate `<script type="text/javascript>...</script>` block.  Then assign an `id` or `class` to your parent div in order for JQuery to select it and the `hover()` function to trigger a `hide()` and `show()`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myParent').hover(function() {
        $(this).children().show();
    },
    function() {
        $(this).children().hide();
    });
});
</script>

<div id="myParent">
    <div>delete</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks to both of you, But i have a lot of div like shown below, that's why I use inline javascript. Is there anyway to avoid using inline for this case?


     <div id="myParent">
       <div>delete</div>
     </div>

     <div id="myParent">
       <div>delete</div>
     </div>

     <div id="myParent">
       <div>delete</div>
     </div>

Comment: JQuery can easily handle lots of elements, there is absolutely no need for inline javascript when using jquery.  Simply give each element a unique ID and have a single jquery script select using that.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if you are having the flicker problem because of the difference in the parent div height once you hover over the child. I don't see your CSS so I can't tell for sure. One way to avoid this problem is to change it's visibility. Using `display:none` will hide the element so that it will not take up it's original space. Using `visibility:hidden` hides the content but leaves the original space of the object... I threw together some sample code using unobstrusive jQuery and a confirmation dialog box.

*Notes*

- The row id to delete is contained in the `name` attribute of the parent class.
- The parent div has the class name of `deleteme`, as IDs must be unique.
- If the Delete link takes up too much space, you can replace the child `div` with a `span` to keep it inline.

HTML

```
<div class="deleteme" name="cid001">
 Hover over me #1 (comment id=cid001)
 <div> [X] Delete?</div>
</div>

<div class="deleteme" name="cid002">
  Hover over me #2 (comment id=cid002)
 <div> [X] Delete?</div>
</div>
```

Script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.deleteme').hover(function(){
  $(this).find('div').css('visibility','visible')
 },function(){
  $(this).find('div').css('visibility','hidden');
 });
 $('.deleteme div')
  .css('visibility','hidden')
  .click(function(){
  // Confirmation
  if (confirm("Are you sure?")){
   alert( "delete row with ID = " + $(this).parent().attr('name') ); // the name contains the comment ID to delete
  }
 })
})
```

Comment: hi fudgey,

all of your solution help me a lot and solve my problem

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would do this using the `hover()` method:

**HTML**:

```
<div id="comment-1" class="comment">
   <p>some content</p>
   <div class="delete">[x] Delete</div>  
</div>
<div id="comment-2" class="comment">
   <p>some content</p>  
   <div class="delete">[x] Delete</div>  
</div>
```

**jQuery**:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   // hide the delete div(s)
   $('.delete').hide();
   // bind the click event of the delete div(s) to remove the parent 'comment' div
   $('.delete').bind('click', function() {
       $(this).parent('.comment').remove();
     }); 
   // bind the hover event, 
   // in callback calls show() on the child with class 'delete'
   // out callback calls hide() on the child with class ''delete'
   $('.comment').hover(function() {
       $(this).children('.delete').show();
     }, function() {
       $(this).children('.delete').hide();
     });
   });
```

Working example on [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/egoda)

Comment: hi beggs

thanks for your response, your answer help me a lot and solve my problem.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this? I'm not sure what you are trying to say.

```
jQuery("div#parent").bind("mouseover", function(){
  // Do mouse over code here
});

jQuery("div#parent").bind("mouseout", function(){
  // Do mouse out code here
});
```

Comment: This functionality can be combined using the hover() method.